# Check if specific value exists in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql column called categories. It can contain single or multiple values like this: 1 or 2 or 1,2,3 or 2,12...

I try to get all rows containing value 2.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE categories LIKE '2'";
$rows = mysql_query($query);
```

This returns row if column only has value 2 but not 1,2,3 or 2,12. How I can get all rows including value 2?

Comment: Use -> `%2%` in your query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: Or function `find_in_set` like `find_in_set('2', categories)`.

Comment: find_in_set works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following:

`%` is a wildcard so it will match `2` or `1,2`, etc. Anything on either side of a `2`. The problem is it could match 21, 22, etc.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE categories LIKE '%2%'";
```

Instead you should consider the [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) mysql function which expects a comma separated list for the value.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE find_in_set('2', `categories`)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @jitendrapurohut said, you can do it using

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE categories LIKE '%2%'";
$rows = mysql_query($query);
```

But is really bad to store collections like this. A better aproach is as follow:

1. categories(id_c, name) => A table with each category
2. my_table(id_m [, ...])
3. categories_my_table(id_c, id_m)

Then use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table m
INNER JOIN categories_my_table cm ON m.id_m = cm.id_m
INNER JOIN categories c ON cm.id_c = c.id_c
WHERE
c.id_c = 2;
```

EDIT:
@e4c5 link explains why it is bad to store collections like this...

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE categories LIKE '%2%' AND categories!='1,2,3' AND categories!='2,12';
```

Comment: Hi, @Jqrp  try this query

Comment: This won't work very well - for example it will include rows where the category is '23' or '102' for example, but those aren't wanted.